# How to increase the height of top side of block by filling of texts?

Tags: css

My block has position: absolute, and I cannot change the height automatically, when content is filled into the block.
Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/wwvbvzv4/1/

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.outer > p {
  
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <p>
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
    </p>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <p>
      My text block <br> 
    </p>
</div>
```

i need to fix bottom side position and to change height by increase top side.
Behavior should be like here https://jsfiddle.net/wwvbvzv4/5/ but instead inline use absolute

Comment: sorry couldnt understand... what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: there is no position: absolute property in your code

Comment: @RRR, i need to fix bottom side position and to change height by increase top side

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan, maybe exists some way to do it with position: absolute?

Comment: your question is still not clear. be more specific.

Comment: @JayPatel, here is example https://jsfiddle.net/wwvbvzv4/5/ with position: inline, i need to use position: absolute

Comment: are you consider "display" property as "position"?

Comment: do you want to apply dynamic height to the `.outer` div ?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan, yes, under influence <p>

Comment: but it's already has  dynamic height: http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/wwvbvzv4/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.outer {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100px;
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
        }
        .outer > p {

            width: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px dashed red;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
        <p>
            My text block <br> 
            My text block <br> 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
        <p>
            My text block <br> 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
        <p>
            My text block <br> 
            My text block <br> 
            My text block <br> 
            My text block <br> 
        </p>
    </div>
```

is this you want?

Comment: The min-height property of .outer may be affecting the layout. change the value based on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.outer > p {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>
    My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <p>
    My text block
    <br>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <p>
    My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>My text block
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```